# Fancybox not working on dynamically added external links

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I  have a list of items as follows

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="http://toExtUrl/img.jpg" class="should-popout">
  <img src="http://mywebsite.com/icon.png"></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

toExtUrl/img.jpg is added dynamically and it may sometimes shows pdf or HTML content instead of images(This is always external link). I'm trying to give the fancybox popout effect for whatever comes with href attribute of '.should-popout'.

But while clicking it just redirection to external url happens. My fancybox option is as follows

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $('a.should-popout').fancybox({
    'autoDimensions' : true,
    'autoScale' : true
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'showCloseButton' : true
 });
});
```

What may be the error in the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to upgrade to v3 and use like this:

```
$().fancybox({
  selector : '.should-popout'
});
```

v2 tries to get current selector (using this handy https://api.jquery.com/selector/ property) and then uses that to create delegated event handler. But jQuery v3 removed that feature and therefore this does not work anymore. And therefore v3 allows this new syntax.

Comment: Thanks worked.. +1.  i was using fancybox version 3 and following doc for older version. @milind Patel also suggesting the same..

Comment: Yes, he posted his answer while I was (slowly) typing :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to overcome the situation where the popup says "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later", If the external link also dynamically handling their images?

Comment: The default content type is "image", but, if it is something different, for example, `pdf`, you should set `data-type="iframe"`. There is not difference if this is external link or not, it should work fine (as long as your url is correct and the script can detect content type)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read docs first.

[Read it here](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage)

***For v3***

```
$().fancybox({
  selector : 'a.should-popout',
  loop     : true
});
```

For Older versions

[Read it here in api method](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

```
$(document).on('click','a.should-popout',function(event){
    $.fancybox.close(true);
    $.fancybox.open($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks .. it worked.. +1 i was using fancybox version 3 and following doc for older version.